# Deleting a pending intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I am trying to delete a alarm from the alarm manager which is using a pending intent to broadcast, and a broadcast receiver is used to catch and carry out the process,the deleteReminder function is getting called, but the intent is still firing when the time comes.
If there is something wrong in the code please let me know.

```
public class ReminderManager {

private Context mContext;
private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
private Intent i;

public ReminderManager(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
}
public void setReminder(Long taskId, Calendar when) {

    System.out.println("setReminder Called");

    i = new Intent(mContext, Receiver.class);
    i.putExtra(Database.KEY_ROWID, (long) taskId);

    Toast.makeText(mContext, "setReminder" + Fragment.uniqueId,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,
            Fragment.uniqueId, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
}

public void deleteReminder(int uniqueID) {

    System.out.println("deleteReminder Called");
    i = new Intent(mContext, Receiver.class);
    i.putExtra(Database.KEY_ROWID, (long) uniqueID);

    Toast.makeText(mContext, "deleteReminder" + uniqueID,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, uniqueID, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
            mAlarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, uniqueID, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
}
}
```

Comment: Is Fragment.uniqueId the same as param uniqueId?

Comment: they have the same values , just coming from different places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a boolean to the setReminder function to check if i want to delete or not, and a if statement to add or delete the alarm from the alarm manager, it reduced the size of the code and is working properly.

```
public class ReminderManager {

private Context mContext;
private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
private Intent i;

// Constructor to set the context and set the alarmManager
public ReminderManager(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
}

// used to create a pending intent using task id and Calendar object
public void setReminder(Long taskId, Calendar when, boolean delete) {

    System.out.println("setReminder Called");

    i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    i.putExtra(NotesDatabase.KEY_ROWID, (long) taskId);

    Toast.makeText(mContext, "setReminder" + AddFragment.uniqueId,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // broadcast !! // change the
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,
            AddFragment.uniqueId, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    if(delete == false){
    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
    }else{
        pi.cancel();
        mAlarmManager.cancel(pi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
public void deleteReminder(int uniqueID) {

    System.out.println("deleteReminder Called");
    i = new Intent(mContext, Receiver.class);
    i.putExtra(Database.KEY_ROWID, (long) uniqueID);

    Toast.makeText(mContext, "deleteReminder" + uniqueID,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,
            Fragment.uniqueId, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    mAlarmManager.cancel(pi);

}
```

Comment: i tried this, but the alarm screen still pops up and the `intent i` is also getting fired.. :(